# How do I remove a photo from a Google+ album without deleting it?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

If you accidentally add a photo to a Google+ album (e.g. via the "Move" button), it seems there's no way to remove it without deleting it.

Comment: Did you try use move again to move it to a different album?

Comment: That may work, but in most cases, I don't want to move it to another album.

Comment: All photos are in an album of some sort. Even the auto-backup photos are in a special auto-backup album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to the album in question

   (Google+ -> Photos -> More -> Albums -> Select your album)
2. In the top-right corner, select "Organize"
3. You will now see a list of all your photos with actions, including "Delete" which will delete it from the album only.